# How should we deal with "cross-cutting" questions?

Tags: feature-request

With more and more "soft" Stack Exchange sites popping up, it feels there is an increasing amount of questions that "could" in principle be on-topic in multiple sites.

A recent example is [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/102698/male-classmates-rank-female-students-according-to-physical-appearance): the question is about sexual harassment in college, which is clearly in scope here; however, the question could have easily also gone to [IPS](http://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/), and would have certainly been in scope there as well. Now, the twist is that I am pretty sure that the question would have received fairly different answers at IPS - here on Academia many users seemed to be in favor of reporting the students, while on IPS the answers would have probably gone more into a "work with the students to increase awareness" direction. It feels to me that OP has, probably without knowing it, biased the advise she has received by her choice of where to ask the question.

It seems to me that a network-wide feature for controlled cross-posting would be awesome. Is this something that has been considered? Is there something fundamentally wrong with such a feature?

Comment: This isn't the kind of thing an individual site can propose and develop. It belongs on (the) Meta, where it has been effectively though not quite officially status-declined for a long time. There are 125 question results for "cross posting" and many are duplicates.

Comment: And [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199989/255554) is a similar proposal on [meta.se].